# Is it possible login into website programmatically with android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-webservice

I am trying to login into https://thingspeak.com/login website programmatically.
I have written blow android program but its not help me to login. pls tell me what am i doing wrong.

```
//inside thread function

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User ID", "****"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "*****"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sign In", "Sign In"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

//after thread function getting called, below line is from oncreate method

WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("https://thingspeak.com/channels/42085");
```

I am able to load the website but its tells This channel is not public because its not logged in. pls help me out. thanks in advance.

username:niru

password:helloworld@123

Answer (score 2):

The method you are searching for is called HTTP basic authentication. In the case that your target server is using SSL it gets really difficult because you need a certificate.

**Such a authentication is working as these steps:**

- Login form URL.
- Login form data.
- URL for authentication.
- Http request / response header.

  ```
  public class HttpUrlConnectionExample {

  private List<String> cookies;
  private HttpsURLConnection conn;

  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      String url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth";
      String gmail = "https://mail.google.com/mail/";

      HttpUrlConnectionExample http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample();

      // make sure cookies is turn on
      CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

      // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
      String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
      String postParams = http.getFormParams(page, "username@gmail.com", "password");

      // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
      // authentication
      http.sendPost(url, postParams);

      // 3. success then go to gmail.
      String result = http.GetPageContent(gmail);
      System.out.println(result);
  }

  private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

      URL obj = new URL(url);
      conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

      // Acts like a browser
      conn.setUseCaches(false);
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "accounts.google.com");
      conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
              "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
      for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
          conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
      }
      conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setDoInput(true);

      // Send post request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
      wr.writeBytes(postParams);
      wr.flush();
      wr.close();

      int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
      System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
      System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

      BufferedReader in =
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
          response.append(inputLine);
      }
      in.close();
      // System.out.println(response.toString());

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

      URL obj = new URL(url);
      conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

      // default is GET
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

      conn.setUseCaches(false);

      // act like a browser
      conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
              "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
      if (cookies != null) {
          for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
              conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
          }
      }
      int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
      System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

      BufferedReader in =
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
          response.append(inputLine);
      }
      in.close();

      // Get the response cookies
      setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

      return response.toString();

  }

  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
          throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

      System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

      // Google form id
      Element loginform = doc.getElementById("gaia_loginform");
      Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
      List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
      for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
          String key = inputElement.attr("name");
          String value = inputElement.attr("value");

          if (key.equals("Email"))
              value = username;
          else if (key.equals("Passwd"))
              value = password;
          paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
      }

      // build parameters list
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      for (String param : paramList) {
          if (result.length() == 0) {
              result.append(param);
          } else {
              result.append("&" + param);
          }
      }
      return result.toString();
  }

  public List<String> getCookies() {
      return cookies;
  }

  public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
      this.cookies = cookies;
  }
  }
  ```

**Important resource:**
[How to automate login a website – Java example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/)