# How to login to a JSP webpage from Android client?

Tags: android, authentication

This is the site I would need logging in to:

```
  <base href="login.jsp">
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE></TITLE>
  <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
  <LINK href="css/emda.css" type="text/css" rel="STYLESHEET">
  <script src="css/list.js"> </script>
  <script src="css/edit.js"> </script>
  <script src="css/enc.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function abc() {
     alert(md5(document.loginForm.j_password.value));
   }
   function encryptPass(){
       document.loginForm.j_password.value = md5(document.loginForm.j_password.value);
   }
  </script>

  </HEAD>


  <BODY leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" dir="rtl" background="images/strips-w.jpg" />

  <input type="hidden" name="helpUrl" value="/emda/com/objectj/resources/jsp/help/vorod.help.html"/>

  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl">
  <tr><td valign="top">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl">
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" valign="top">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl">
              <tr dir="rtl" valign="top">
                <td width="120"><img src="images/toprt.jpg" width="120" height="90" border="0" usemap="#emdakhodro"></td>
                <td width="227"><img src="images/title.jpg" width="227" height="90"></td>
                <td width="*" height="79" valign="bottom" background="images/mid.jpg">&nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="50" dir="rtl"><img src="images/toplft1.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl">
        <tr>
            <td width="120" valign="top" background="images/strips-rt.jpg">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="*" height="*" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <table width="100%" height="100" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl">
      <tr valign="bottom">
        <td width="100" background="strips-rt.jpg">&nbsp;</td>
          <td valign="middle" width="*" align="center" class="text" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" bgcolor="#666699">

                <tr>
                  <td width="100%" class="textTitle"><div align="center">به خوش آمديد!</div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        <td width="100" background="strips-lft.jpg">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
      <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl">
        <tr valign="top">
          <td width="100" background="strips-rt.jpg">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="*" align="center" class="textB" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

            <table width="*" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"  dir="ltr">

                <tr valign="bottom">
                  <td><img src="images/pgblue.jpg" width="305" height="185" border="0"></td>
                  <td width="*">

                        <table border=3 bordercolor="#666699" cellpadding=5 class="text" dir="rtl">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                              لطفاً شناسه و گذرواژه خود را وارد کنيد <br>

                          <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check">

                            <table width="85%" border="0">

                              <tr>

                                <td width="34%" align="right" class="text">شناسه:</td>
                                <td width="66%" align="right">
                                      <input name="j_username" type="text" class="field" size="20"/>
                                    </td>
                              </tr>

                              <tr>

             <td width="34%" align="right" class="text">گذرواژه:</td>
             <td width="66%" align="right">
  <!--<input name="j_password" type="hidden" />-->
  <!--<input name="j_password2" type="password" class="field" size="20" />-->
  <input name="j_password" type="password" class="field" size="20" />
  </td>
           </tr>

                            <tr style="display: none;">

             <td width="34%" align="right" class="text">شماره داخلی:</td>
             <td width="66%" align="right">
  <!--<input name="j_password" type="hidden" />-->
  <!--<input name="j_password2" type="password" class="field" size="20" />-->
  <input name="telFieldNo" type="text" class="field" size="20" maxlength="8" value="10"/>
  </td>
           </tr>

                                <td width="34%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="66%" align="center">
                                        <br>
                                        <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="emdaButton"  onclick="encryptPass();"
                                                 value="ورود"/>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:help();">راهنما</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                              </tr>

                            </table>
                          </form></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
              <br>
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" class="text">
                <tr>
                  <td align="right"> تاريخ : 2/11/1397</td>
                  <td align="left"> ساعت: 23:26:50</td>
                  <td align="left"><span style="color: #CCCCFF;" >A &nbsp;</span>
                      اگر گذرواژه خود را فراموش کرده ايد، <a href="/emda">اينجا</a> را کليک کنيد.</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
            <th width="100" background="strips-lft.jpg">&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
    </table>



            </td>
            <td width="50" valign="top" background="images/strips-lft.jpg"><img src="images/strips-lft.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

  </td></tr></table>

  <script>
    document.loginForm.j_username.focus();
      function signIn(){
          var seed = 31;
          var hash = 0;
          var str = document.loginForm.j_password2.value;
          for( i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
             hash = (hash * seed) + str.charCodeAt(i);
          document.loginForm.j_password.value = hash;
          document.loginForm.submit();
      }
  </script>
  </BODY>
```

I want to sent username and password from android client and get login response  from this page.

The main question is how to interact with this page.

I know that it may be my elementary question, but I need to show you the initial solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible login into website programmatically with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935897/is-it-possible-login-into-website-programmatically-with-android)

Comment: Create a file, copy and paste the entire code into that file. Save it into the `raw` folder as an html file format, then load it as a webpage using `Webview` API. Remember to enable JavaScript on WebView so as to make the JavaScript code works on your web view. Also pay more attention to security. Good luck!